# Can I write unit test for following in spock?

Tags: groovy, spock

```
public boolean accept(File directory, String fileName) {
    boolean fileOK = true;

    if (name != null) {
        fileOK &= fileName.startsWith(name);
    }

    if (pattern != null) {
        fileOK &= Pattern.matches(regex, fileName);
    }

    if (extension != null) {
        fileOK &= fileName.endsWith('.' + extension);
    }
    return fileOK;
}
```

Comment: You check `pattern` is not null, then compare with `regex`, also where do `name` and `extension` come from

Answer (score 5):

Below is another way of writing it. I used data-driven approach as you have to test multiple scenarios (multiple if's in the method)

```
def "should accept valid filenames"() {
    expect:
    foobar.accept(new File("/tmp"), fileName)

    where:
    fileName << ["valid_filename_1", "valid_filename_2", "valid_filename_n"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

```
def "file should be valid"() {
    setup:
        def dir = new File("/tmp")
        def fileName = "foo.bar"

    when:
        boolean valid = foobar.accept(dir, fileName)

    then:
        valid
}
```

Comment: `expect: foobar.accept(dir, fileName)` is a better match in this case.